# "Typeahead is not a function" ERROR

Tags: jquery, node.js, mean-stack, meanjs, typeahead

I'm currently unable to use typeahead because of this error:
[image]

I've included jquery and the typeahead packages:

```
<script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="libs/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
```

Both managed with npm.

I'm calling typeahead as follows using the template from the twitter typeahead website:

```
$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'people',
  source: substringMatcher($scope.people)
});
```

I'm developing under a MEAN.js framework... am I forgetting to include something somewhere? None of the other posts have been able to help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So jquery can be picky about how you import libraries/scripts that aren't jquery. Generally you want to import `jquery.js` last so that functions in other files can be called when you do `$(..).typeahead()` for instance. Try modifying your script imports like below, that *should* fix the issue.

```
<script src="libs/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried this, and it threw a few errors saying: _"Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"_ and _" Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"_

Comment: Do you have any other ideas? @Daniel Gonzalez

Comment: If you could post your source, I could take a better look at how you're structuring everything. However, I was able to import everything in a simple html below by reversing the order of the import (apparently typeAhead calls jquery, so you should be importing that first).
`<head>
 <!-- Script files -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="typeahead.bundle"></script>
</head>
<script>
$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'people',
});
</script>`

Comment: Also, potentially unrelated, when I downloaded the typeahead source files I saved it as a .bundle when going [here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js). Then all you'd have to do in the imports is `<script src="your-directory-to/typeahead.bundle"></script>`. Let me know what happens when you try this.

Comment: I actually found a different way of approaching this and abandoned this method, but I approved your comment in case it helps someone else!

Comment: Sweet! Glad you figured it out. Tried to shoot you a message earlier but guess that isn't an option on StackOverflow... Good luck with your project!